# Obtaining chemical graph complexity index from SMILES or InChl

Tags: cheminformatics

I wonder if anyone knows a readily available way to obtain some chemical graph complexity index (like the J index) from the SMILES or InChl representations?I'm looking for some existing implementation, e.g. in R, or OpenBabel, prior to trying to define mine if no one else exist... Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what the J index is, so it's certainly not already implemented in Open Babel. It likely wouldn't be hard to implement.

Comment: Have you looked at a package like RDKit? I'm not sure on the topological indices etc. but the package is quite extensive.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Certainly the RDKit allows to calculate topological indeces. For anyone interested in the same thing: after some research I also found The Chemistry Development Kit, which allows for that and has an R interface (RCDK). Also found MathChem, which allows to calculate a wider variaty of indexes (https://draganstevanovic.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/mathchem-match-9.pdf). Best

Comment: @Tintanjarafe can you please add a reference for the J index? The CDK has several complexity-related descriptors, but I would not mind thinking of implementing this descriptor, but I need to know the algorithm. Was it published somewhere?

Comment: @EgonWillighagen. Sure, it's also known as the Balaban's J index. Here are links to the original publication and to the page in MathWorld: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0009261482800092, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BalabanIndex.html. Thank you!

Comment: This is a very old question, but if folks are still interested perhaps this is a useful bit of code: https://github.com/maxhodak/keras-molecules/pull/32/commits/dbbb790e74e406faa70b13e8be8104d9e938eba2